# Competing Consumers

Tags: spring-integration, eip

I want to configure a spring integration application so that if I put a number of tasks, each represented by one message, on a channel then one of a group of endpoints will pick the next task and process it. This would entail some thread pool executor service I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use a dispatcher + task executor with the channel (aka *ExecutorChannel*). That way any endpoint (e.g. `service-activator`) consuming from the channel will be invoked asynchronously using dispatcher's thread pool.

In the following example, any messages landing on channel `channel01` will be consumed by the `jobLauncher` service within one of the `taskExecutor` threads.

```
<int:channel id="channel01">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor">
</int:channel>

<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="2"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="channel01" ref="jobLauncher">
```